# How to get absolute path of file or directory, that does *not* exist?

Tags: c, file, file-io, relative-path, absolute-path

How can I determine the absolute path of a file or directory from a given relative path in C/C++ on GNU/Linux?
I know about `realpath()`, but it does not work on non-existing files.

Let's say the user enters `../non-existant-directory/file.txt`, and the programs working directory is `/home/user/`.
What I need is a function that returns `/home/non-existant-directory/file.txt`.

I need this function to check if a given path is in a certain subdirectory or not.

Comment: I do not think anything like this exists built in. you are going to have to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `realpath`. If it fails, start removing path components from the end one at a time and retrying `realpath` until it succeeds. Then append the components you removed back onto the result of the successful `realpath` call.

If you're sure the containing directory exists and you just want to make a file there, you only have to remove at most one component.

Another approach would be to just *create* the file first, then call `realpath`.

Comment: This won't work if there are `..` or `.`s in the nonexistent part of the filename. E.g. `/foo/bar/this_dir_doesn't_exist/../../baz` should be normalised to `/foo/baz` but with your method it will be unchanged. I think you need to resolve `..` and `.` first.

Comment: @Timmmm: You can't resolve them before calling `realpath` (or reimplementing it yourself) since you don't know if the component prior to a `..` is a symlink. You just need to apply `..` components in the tail *after* following the procedure in my answer if they might be present.

Comment: Hmm very good point - so, do your method and then resolve `..` afterwards. I wish Linux had a syscall for this.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a very old topic, but in case someone comes here looking for an answer to if `realpath` will work when one or more path components in its operand is missing:

The answer, at least as of `coreutils v. 8+`, is "yes" on most Linux variants, if you supply the "`-m`" option to it.  Here's the relevant help text:

```
$ realpath --help
Usage: realpath [OPTION]... FILE...
Print the resolved absolute file name;
all but the last component must exist

  -e, --canonicalize-existing  all components of the path must exist
  -m, --canonicalize-missing   no components of the path need exist
  -L, --logical                resolve '..' components before symlinks
  -P, --physical               resolve symlinks as encountered (default)
  -q, --quiet                  suppress most error messages
      --relative-to=FILE       print the resolved path relative to FILE
      --relative-base=FILE     print absolute paths unless paths below FILE
  -s, --strip, --no-symlinks   don't expand symlinks
  -z, --zero                   separate output with NUL rather than newline

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

Here's an example on a machine with `coreutils v. 8.22` installed:

```
$ pwd
/home/alice/foo/bar
$ ls /home/alice/foo/bar/baz/quux/splat
ls: cannot access /home/alice/foo/bar/baz/quux/splat: No such file or directory
$ realpath -e ../../foo/bar/baz/quux/splat
realpath: ‘../../foo/bar/baz/quux/splat’: No such file or directory
$ realpath -m ../../foo/bar/baz/quux/splat
/home/alice/foo/bar/baz/quux/splat
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this question was about the C programming language, not bash.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @R.. GitHub, you can build this functionality on `realpath()`. Here is an example function, which uses `realpath()` to determine the canonical form of the portion of the path which exists, and appends the non-existent portion of the path to it.

Since `realpath()` operates on C-style strings, I decided to use them here too. But the function can easily be re-written to use `std::string` (just don't forget to free `canonical_file_path` after copying it to an `std::string`!).

Please note that duplicate "/" entries are not removed from the portion of the path which does not exist; it is simply appended to canonical form of the portion which does exist.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Return the input path in a canonical form. This is achieved by expanding all
// symbolic links, resolving references to "." and "..", and removing duplicate
// "/" characters.
//
// If the file exists, its path is canonicalized and returned. If the file,
// or parts of the containing directory, do not exist, path components are
// removed from the end until an existing path is found. The remainder of the
// path is then appended to the canonical form of the existing path,
// and returned. Consequently, the returned path may not exist. The portion
// of the path which exists, however, is represented in canonical form.
//
// If successful, this function returns a C-string, which needs to be freed by
// the caller using free().
//
// ARGUMENTS:
//   file_path
//   File path, whose canonical form to return.
//
// RETURNS:
//   On success, returns the canonical path to the file, which needs to be freed
//   by the caller.
//
//   On failure, returns NULL.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
char *make_file_name_canonical(char const *file_path)
{
  char *canonical_file_path  = NULL;
  unsigned int file_path_len = strlen(file_path);

  if (file_path_len > 0)
  {
    canonical_file_path = realpath(file_path, NULL);
    if (canonical_file_path == NULL && errno == ENOENT)
    {
      // The file was not found. Back up to a segment which exists,
      // and append the remainder of the path to it.
      char *file_path_copy = NULL;
      if (file_path[0] == '/'                ||
          (strncmp(file_path, "./", 2) == 0) ||
          (strncmp(file_path, "../", 3) == 0))
      {
        // Absolute path, or path starts with "./" or "../"
        file_path_copy = strdup(file_path);
      }
      else
      {
        // Relative path
        file_path_copy = (char*)malloc(strlen(file_path) + 3);
        strcpy(file_path_copy, "./");
        strcat(file_path_copy, file_path);
      }

      // Remove path components from the end, until an existing path is found
      for (int char_idx = strlen(file_path_copy) - 1;
           char_idx >= 0 && canonical_file_path == NULL;
           --char_idx)
      {
        if (file_path_copy[char_idx] == '/')
        {
          // Remove the slash character
          file_path_copy[char_idx] = '\0';

          canonical_file_path = realpath(file_path_copy, NULL);
          if (canonical_file_path != NULL)
          {
            // An existing path was found. Append the remainder of the path
            // to a canonical form of the existing path.
            char *combined_file_path = (char*)malloc(strlen(canonical_file_path) + strlen(file_path_copy + char_idx + 1) + 2);
            strcpy(combined_file_path, canonical_file_path);
            strcat(combined_file_path, "/");
            strcat(combined_file_path, file_path_copy + char_idx + 1);
            free(canonical_file_path);
            canonical_file_path = combined_file_path;
          }
          else
          {
            // The path segment does not exist. Replace the slash character
            // and keep trying by removing the previous path component.
            file_path_copy[char_idx] = '/';
          }
        }
      }

      free(file_path_copy);
    }
  }

  return canonical_file_path;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for multiple `../` in the fictitious part of the path. I would ideally want to get rid of all `./` and `../` in the string regardless if the path exists. `_fullpath()` on Windows does it. I don't really understand the use case of `realpath()` failing on a non-existent path. You can check a path with `stat()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do something like this:

```rs
let pbuf = std::path::PathBuf::from_str("somewhere/something.json").unwrap();
let parent = pbuf.parent().unwrap().canonicalize().unwrap_or(std::env::current_dir().unwrap());
let file = pbuf.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
let final_path = parent.join(file).to_str().unwrap().to_owned();
```

if parent path does not exist (or fails for whatever reason), it will attach current directory in it's place.